# Fitting and scaling two images side by side in grid layout

Tags: android, image, layout, grid, scale

I have two images--a play button on the left, and a boombox on the right. I am trying to scale the height and widths of these images to look like this

[image]

Though my code is producing this:

[image]

Essentially, the files are pretty big and not sized correctly, but I don't know why the boombox image is getting cut off. I want the whole boombox to fit, and then the play button to adjust its height according to the height of the boombox.

This is my layout code, though I think I need to make big changes:

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"

    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/play_stop_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:src="@drawable/play_button_final"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/boombox"
        android:id="@+id/boombox"
        />


</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"

    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/play_stop_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:src="@drawable/play_button_final"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/boombox"
        android:id="@+id/boombox"
        />


</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Nope, no luck. Still the same thing